# Why below code is giving wrong output outside loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have below python code

```
class Cust: 
    def __init__(self): 
        self.name 

surname=["Lai","Sharma","Max"]
def fetchName(surnames):
    custinst=Cust
    custinst.name="Gaurav"+surnames
    return custinst

finalname=[]
print("###inside loop###")
for i in range(len(surname)):
    finalname.append(fetchName(surname[i]))
    print(finalname[i].name)
print("\n###Outside Loop###\n") 
print (finalname[0].name)
print (finalname[1].name)
print (finalname[2].name)
```

and below is the output

```
 ###inside loop###
 GauravLai
 GauravSharma
 GauravMax

 ###Outside Loop###

 GauravMax
 GauravMax
 GauravMax
```

Issue is why outside loop all the values are coming as last assigned value i.e. GauravMax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're modifying the `Cust` class instance instead of creating a new instance of it every loop:

```
def fetchName(surnames):
    custinst=Cust
    custinst.name="Gaurav"+surnames
    return custinst
```

Here `Cust` is the object that contains the class itself, not an instance of it.  You can verify this by doing `print(Cust.name)` after `Inside Loop`, which will print `GauravMax`.

You have to create a new instance by calling the constructor:

```
def fetchName(surnames):
    custinst=Cust()
    custinst.name="Gaurav"+surnames
    return custinst
```

Currently, your constructor accesses the `name` property but it hasn't been set, so it will cause an error. You could just avoid that since it's not doing anything:

```
def Cust():
    pass
```

But consider using the parameters of the constructor when instancing the object:

```
def Cust():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

and then pass the name as a parameter:

```
def fetchName(surnames):
    return Cust("Gaurav"+surnames)
```